# How to Call Excel VBA functions from VSTO Application addin

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto

Seen a quite a few examples of calling VSTO functions from VBA, using Automation Add-In, COM Interop etc but not the other way round.

I have an Excel application VSTO addin that is only designed to work with only the one Excel workbook. This Excel workbook is a legacy workbook since office 2003 and contains many VBA code.

How can I call these VBA functions and subs from VSTO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it using the `Application.Run` method.  E.g.

```
ThisApplication.Run("MyVbaMacroName",
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: LOL? seriously Missing? I'll try that. Thanks!